# Python-pptx: How to append a new slide to a powerpoint slide from a template slide

Tags: python-3.x, slide, python-pptx

I have a query w.r.t to python-pptx. Is it possible that I have a template slide which contains several charts in it. This charts are supposed to be updated weekly and then supposed to be added to a new slide (Not in template slide which I have). I was wondering if there exist an append_slide functionality or something similar. Below is piece of code which I used to update chart present on my template slide but now I want this slide with updated chart on slide which is part of different powerpoint file:

```
 chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
    chart_data.add_series('Quarterly_data', input_df2['Quarter'])
    
    chart1.replace_data(chart_data)

  # Now I want to save this data or to be precise this slide in template powerpoint on other powerpoint 
    file let say "ABC.pptx"

     prs.save(r"D:\ABC.pptx")  # Appended as new slide
```

Comment: Am I right in understanding you want to create the slide in a presentation that doesn't have the template / master slide in it?

Comment: Yes. My problem statement is to add a slide from Template slide which have 10 slides in it and I want to do some modification in some chart data as specified in above code to template slide let say slide number 1 and add this new slide into some other powerpoint presentation. Hope it is more or less make sense. @MartinPacker

Comment: Then I don't think you can. I'd be more inclined to copy a template presentation to work on with md2pptx and save that newly hatched presentation. Then I'd find a way to automate copying that presentation into the appropriate place in the weekly presentation. (Or else build the weekly presentation entirely using md2pptx, using this copied presentation as the base.)